# What else (if anything) can I support in the same pot with my lime trees?

Tags: fruit-trees, containers

I have two lime trees in pots, because I need to bring them indoors during the winter.  Additionally, we recently found that keeping mint in our lawn garden was a bad idea, since it spreads so vigorously.

Can we move the mint into our pots with the lime trees to keep the mint contained?  Will the mint compete in any way with the tree itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend putting your mint in the pots with the trees - mint roots go up to 18 inches downwards in the soil, and spread prolifically, and would compete with the trees. Pot the mint separately. It can be grown in the ground without taking over provided you insert a root barrier down to 18 inches all round the area you want it to occupy.